# Renaming columns in a dataframe using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, transformation

Say I have a dataframe (df) which looks as given below
[image]

It has columns 3 columns all named the same (L, L, L). I want to rename the columns as L1, L2 and L3 based on their column position. I expect the optput to look as given below.

[image]

I can do it using the code
df.columns = ['Input', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3']

However, I believe a way must be available where I loop over all columns (or chosen columns) so that this can be automated for any dataframe.

Many thanks in advance for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use

```py
df.columns = [f'{col}{i}' if col == 'L' else col for i, col in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Comment: @Mortz OP's column is `['Input', 'L', 'L', 'L']`. thus it's fine to start from 0.

Comment: Okay, they say they want to rename it to `L1, L2, L3` in the question - which is why I added `start`

Comment: @Mortz Index of `L` in `['Input', 'L', 'L', 'L']` is 1, 2, 3

Comment: Ah, right! Sorry, I missed that...